# Get current download speed as a number

Tags: networking, download

`nload` is handy when it comes to live monitoring of bandwidth consumption. It displays an ongoing process window and you can look at it. While this is useful for humans, it isn't useful for scripts.

I'd like to get currrent download or upload for particular network interface as a string and be done with it immediately.

Something like this: `nload devices en3`, but without the ongoing process. is this possible?

Comment: must be `nload` ?

Comment: no, not at all.

Answer (score 4):

`ifstat` prints the incoming and outoming traffic in an easy list to parse:

```
ifstat [-i device] [delay] [count]
```

You might need to install it, provided from most package systems, e.g. `apt-get install ifstat` or `yum install ifstat` or similar depending on your system.

Output is like this:

```
$ ifstat -i en3
    en3     
 KB/s in  KB/s out
    0.25      0.00
    0.72      1.06
    0.45      0.07
    ...
```

---

To parse it, you can use e.g. `awk`:

```
$ ifstat -i en3 1s 1 | awk 'NR==3 {print $1}'
47.17
```

Upload would be `$2`.

By default, the unit is Kilobytes/s.